# Filter combobox dropdown options using textbox value in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a form in Access with a textbox and a combobox, and need to filter the combobox dropdown options using the value in the textbox. The textbox contains a `Category` for the choices.

I've done this using

```
SELECT Options.Choice
FROM Options
WHERE (((Options.Category)=[forms]![FormName]![Text10].Value));
```

**Is there a way to refer to the value in `Text10` without explicitly referring to `FormName`?**

I'll need to duplicate this form within the same Access file and changing all combobox row sources for a new form is not feasible. I can't hard code the Category value for each combobox because there are many comboboxes per form, and the value in the textbox will be different on every form. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to whatever form you're currently on in Access using Screen.ActiveForm.  So in your case you'd have:

```
SELECT Options.Choice
FROM Options
WHERE (((Options.Category)=[Screen].[ActiveForm]![Text10].Value));
```

As long as the field name stays constant this should work.

Comment: Darn MSDN didn't mention it's applicable in sql. Much better!